# Compare pandas Dataframe Columns with Set

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, set

I have a pandas dataframe containing a '`date`' column.
I am maintaining a set of whitelisted dates in another set '`date_set`'.

What I am trying to achieve is that in case a '`date`' is present in the `date_set`, I will add true to the '`is_date_whitelisted`' column else false.

Any pointers on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df['is_date_whitelisted'] = df['date'].isin(list(date_set))
```

Comment: Worked. Thanks!

Comment: @Sanchay Glad to help.

Comment: I have a similar problem to this. What if instead of just matches, I want the entire row to be extracted into another dataframe wherever I get a match? For example, if I have an element in the set that appears in my concerned column at row 45, then I would want all column information from row 45 to be extracted and written to a third dataframe. Any idea how this would work?